# Como acessar base mysql de uma rede externa

Tags: android, mysql, delphi, firemonkey

Tenho uma aplicação, em Android com banco de dados MySQL, que funciona perfeitamente dentro de uma rede específica. Porém ao tentar acessar essa mesma base em uma rede externa recebo a seguinte messagem:

> 28000Acess Denied for user 'root'@'meu ip'(using password: YES)

A base MySQL se encontra em um servidor FTP pago, não está dentro da rede empresarial, não tenho um túnel VPN ligado diretamente a ela.

Que tipo de configuração eu altero para conectar nessa base?

Comment: Tente criar um novo usuário para realizar o acesso. O MySQL possui o acesso remoto para o usuário `root` bloqueado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode desbloquear o acesso remoto pelo usuário root da seguinte maneira:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comente a seguinte linha no seu `my.cnf`

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

reinicie o serviço do MySQL